# How to direct user from a splash activity to the main activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I am asked to develop an Android application whose description is this:

> Let’s assume if you like Football or Cricket so much and you can find
> some unknown having the same interests.
>
> You can send Hello to him/her and can chat as well. Fantastic. Let’s
> Jump into the Project Ideas
>
> You can Select the Interest from the menu
>
> Find the person with the common interests and send him Hello request
>
> You can get so much information about your interests.
>
> Chat with Friends
>
> You can build this App using Android Studio.

So I have made a splash screen, register, login page and a user setup activity till now.

I have also designed a dashboard type interface which would display various kinds of interest for the user to choose from. So I would have to make a different main activity for different interests, like if the user chooses sports as interest, the main activity would be different than for the user who choses singing as his/her interest.

What do I do if I want to direct the user from the splash screen to the main activity screen (sports, singing, etc.) of his/her choice? (Example code would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Shared Preference* for this.
Just save your interest in preferences with some tag when you select it like below:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
myEdit.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
myEdit.putInt("age", Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()));

myEdit.apply();
myEdit.commit();
```

**Then you can get it on Splash screen from shared preference like:**

// Make sure to use the same name while getting data that you use while saving it.

```
SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_APPEND);

String S1 = sh.getString("name", "");
int A = sh.getInt("age", 0);
```

You can now use S1 and A variables for whatever you want.

In your case, you can use *if/else* or *switch*.